# After Install Laravel 4 on Ubuntu 12.04 the requested URL / was not found on this server

Tags: laravel, php-5.4

I Installed Laravel 4 on Ubuntu 12.04, I follow these steps from -

```
 http://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/
```

[www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/](http://www.dev-metal.com/install-laravel-4-ubuntu-12-04-lts/)

Activate mod_rewrite

Install the mod_rewrite module (or extension or whatever it is) and restart the Apache:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Open the default vhost config file:

```
sudo nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/default
DocumentRoot /var/www
<Directory /var/www>
```

and change them to

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/public
<Directory /var/www/public>
```

than Install Laravel 4

```
cd /var/www
wget https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/master.zip
unzip master.zip && cd laravel-master/ && mv * ../ && cd ..
rm -r laravel-master && rm master.zip
```

Run the installation with Composer by

```
composer install
```

and restart the server:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

than successfully installed and message : 
[image]

but when I'm trying to run another web project for example

```
http://localhost/demo
```

than error comes like :

```
Not Found

The requested URL /demo was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following to your apache directory configuration.

AllowOverride All

Comment: often times the reason is not having AllowOverride set.

Answer (score 0):

go to the httpd.conf file of the server and remove hash (comment tag) from line showing below

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

it may be created from server side.

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `DocumentRoot` is now set to /var/www/**public** which, i think where your problem is. Try putting your `demo` project folder inside the `public` folder then, try again. If it is a route, add it to `/app/routes.php`